# Question on DataFrame join and copy operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is test code,

```py
testframe = pd.DataFrame({"A":"1","B":"1","C":"1","D":"1"})

dataframe1 = testframe 

#try to remove column C
dataframe1.drop(['C'],axis=1,inplace=True)

#then modify col D, like
>>A B D
  1 1 2

#rename col 'D' to 'E', now dataframe1 contains only 'A' and 'E'
#(does this mean )
dataframe1.rename(columns={"D": "E"}, inplace=True)
print(dataframe1)

# result is ,
>>A B E
  1 1 2
#join two dataframe(is this allowed? it seems that I joined a copy of 'testframe')

testframe = testframe.set_index(['A','B']).join(dataframe1.set_index(['A','B']))

print(testframe)
```

but the result is

```
A B C D E
1 1 1 2 2
```

It looks like joint of two dataframe, but it is not, in fact.

Why is Col D changed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pd.concat method to join two dataframes
[read_this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-concat-function-in-python/)

Comment: Actually, I have tried 'pd.concat', but this function will generate much redundant data, the root cause is dataframe assignment is just a 'shallow copy' by default. Thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is found.

```
    dataframe1 = testframe
    dataframe1.rename(columns={"D": "E"}, inplace=True)
```

code above is just a shallow copy of original 'testframe', so rename will make sense to testframe, and it works after changing code as following with deep copy,

```
    dataframe1 = testframe.copy(deep=True)
```

and also `merge()` will get similar result as `join()` in this case.